# Pace.Js help to link another page when loader finish

Tags: jquery, progress-bar, pace.js

i have the index, but i want to load another page, after he pace.js loader finish, i modify the default properties of time the time intervals, but i want to show the some another page after this loader finish,  i think some pace script code is required. please help.

this is my html

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<title>Casa del nino</title>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rwoIResjU2yc3z8GV/NPeZWAv56rSmLldC3R/AZzGRnGxQQKnKkoFVhFQhNUwEyJ" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-A7FZj7v+d/sdmMqp/nOQwliLvUsJfDHW+k9Omg/a/EheAdgtzNs3hpfag6Ed950n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.4.0/js/tether.min.js" integrity="sha384-DztdAPBWPRXSA/3eYEEUWrWCy7G5KFbe8fFjk5JAIxUYHKkDx6Qin1DkWx51bBrb" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-vBWWzlZJ8ea9aCX4pEW3rVHjgjt7zpkNpZk+02D9phzyeVkE+jo0ieGizqPLForn" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


 <script src="pace/pace.js"></script>
  <link href="pace/themes/green/pace-theme-loading-bar.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<link rel="stylesheet" href="casanino2.css">
</head>

<body class="image"  >

<script>

    Pace.start()

    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

this is my css code

```
  .image{


         background: url('imagenes/20130819180556.jpg') no-repeat center center fixed;
      -webkit-background-size: cover;
      -moz-background-size: cover;
      background-size: cover;
      -o-background-size: cover;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i add

$(document).ready(function () {
    window.setTimeout(function () {
        location.href = "prueba.html";
    }, 3400);
     });